# PasteSpecial in secondary Excel window changes worksheet in primary window

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, paste

I copy and paste formulas frequently, so I wrote a short macro to give me a keyboard shortcut:

```
Sub PasteFormula()
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+F
    Dim TargetRange As Range

    If Application.CutCopyMode Then
        Set TargetRange = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection
        TargetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
End Sub
```

It works exactly as desired, with one undesired pecularity.  Here's how to create a MWE:

1. Open a new workbook Book1.xlsb.  Copy the VBA above into a module, and link up the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+F.
2. Use View -> Window -> New Window to create a second window, so that the windows' titles are "Book1:1" and "Book1:2".
3. In the window "Book1:2" create a second sheet "Sheet2" and open that sheet. Type something in one cell, copy it, go to another cell on the same window, and press Ctrl+Shift+F.

The macro will work--the formula from the first cell is copied, as a formula, into the second cell.  However, *the first window "Book1:1" changes to display Sheet2*. How can I use VBA to run PasteSpecial in a secondary window without changing sheets in the primary window?

## Clarification

I am working in just one workbook, "Book1.xlsb", open in two windows.  That workbook has two sheets; I have Sheet1 open in the first window and Sheet2 open in the second window.

*When I run a PasteSpecial in Sheet2 in the second window (Book1:2), the first window (Book1:1) switches to Sheet2 as well.*

For contrast, if I run a PasteSpecial in the first window (Book1:1), the second window does *not* switch sheets.

I think this behavior is strange.  So my questions are

- Why does Excel do this, and/or
- How can I make Excel not do this?

Comment: Is this scenario talking about 2 separate workbooks or 2 separate sheets? After pasting, do you want the origin of formula to be displayed or the paste destination to be displayed?

Comment: Any reason you don't use already existing keyboard shortcuts to do this?

Comment: There is only one workbook, with two different sheets, each in a different window.  I want to be in one window, do my pasting in that window, and have the first window be unaffected by the entire process.

Comment: @BigBen, is there a keyboard shorcut for pasting formulas?  I only know about Ctrl+Alt+V, then F, then Enter, but that's a lot longer than Ctrl+Shift+F.  I couldn't find any simpler shortcut using Google.

Comment: I was thinking of that - or using Alt+H+V+F (at least in Excel 2016)... admittedly just a little longer than Ctrl+Shift+F. If anything, I'm curious as to how to solve with VBA as well. Very strange behavior.